# In Sklearn, is there a clean way to transform a list of dicts?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a list of dicts that I want to scale. To use sklearn scalers, I need to turn the dicts into lists. Then, I will turn the lists back into dicts. This is what I'm doing:

```
keys = sorted(X[0].keys())
scaler = RobustScaler()
transformed = scaler.fit_transform([[x[k] for k in keys] for x in X])
X = [{k: x[idx] for idx, k in enumerate(keys)} for x in transformed]
```

Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take at this problem yields this solution. It is very similar to yours, just the last part uses `dict()` and `zip()` for a cleaner look (in my opinion).

```
X_original = [
    {'a': 2, 'b': 3},
    {'a': 7, 'b': 6},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 7},
]

keys = sorted(X_original[0].keys())
X_values = [
    [d[k] for k in keys]
    for d in X_original]

scaler = RobustScaler()
X_transformed = scaler.fit_transform(X_values)

X_final = [
    dict(zip(keys, x))
    for x in X_transformed]
```

Inspecting the variables shows the correct result:

```
>>> X_original
[{'a': 2, 'b': 3}, {'a': 7, 'b': 6}, {'a': 1, 'b': 7}]
>>> X_values
[[2, 3], [7, 6], [1, 7]]
>>> X_transformed
[[ 0.         -1.5       ]
 [ 1.66666667  0.        ]
 [-0.33333333  0.5       ]]
>>> X_final
[{'a': 0.0, 'b': -1.5},
 {'a': 1.6666666666666667, 'b': 0.0},
 {'a': -0.3333333333333333, 'b': 0.5}]
```

---

You may have noticed that I like spaced out code. If you want it compact, then it only differs from your code in the last line:

```
X_original = [
    {'a': 2, 'b': 3},
    {'a': 7, 'b': 6},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 7},
]
keys = sorted(X_original[0].keys())

scaler = RobustScaler()
X_transformed = scaler.fit_transform([[d[k] for k in keys] for d in X_original])
X_final = [dict(zip(keys, x)) for x in X_transformed]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be a little bit cleaner:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler

X = [{'a':1, 'b':1}]
keys = sorted(X[0].keys())

scaler = RobustScaler()
transformed = scaler.fit_transform([list(x.values()) for x in X])

result = [dict(zip(keys, x)) for x in transformed]
```

Comment: `.values()` would not preserve the ordering. Hence we will not get the same ordering for every `x`.

Answer (score 1):

When you have your data as list of dict, then pandas Dataframe would be an ideal choice!

After scaling, you have to use the column names of the dataframe to create the dictionary back.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler


my_dict1 = {'a': 1324, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
my_dict2 = {'a': 13, 'b': 123, 'c': 31}
X = [my_dict1, my_dict2]

#[{'a': 1324, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 13, 'b': 123, 'c': 31}]

df = pd.DataFrame(X)
scaler = RobustScaler()
transformed = scaler.fit_transform(df)
transformed_x = [dict(zip(df.columns,x)) for x in transformed]

#[{'a': 1.0, 'b': -1.0, 'c': -1.0}, {'a': -1.0, 'b': 1.0, 'c': 1.0}]
```